# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied Error while Reading the data from Excel file using Jxl jar

Tags: accesscontrolexception

I have one doubt.
    I am trying to host one jsp website.in my website, i am trying to read the data from excel and store it in db.
    I am using jxl jar for connection.It is working fine in local.**But it is not working in web**.it is showing the following error,

```
Warning: Could not instantiate logger jxl.common.log.SimpleLogger using default
Warning: Error accessing system properties.
**java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jxl.nowarnings" "read")**
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:706)
at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.java:238)
at jxl.WorkbookSettings.(WorkbookSettings.java:268)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
at com.nct.dao.Impl.AlumniRegistrationImpl.read(AlumniRegistrationImpl.java:94)
at com.nct.dao.Impl.AlumniRegistrationImpl.massregister_Details(AlumniRegistrationImpl.java:81)
at com.nct.dao.Model.AlumniRegistration.enter_Db_MassDetails(AlumniRegistration.java:22)
at com.nct.Controller.Alumni_Servlet.service(Alumni_Servlet.java:395)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "jxl.nodrawings","read";

in you .java.policy file